# Getting error captcha challenge while registration with disqus plugin

Tags: ajax, laravel, disqus

I have installed Disqus plugin in one of my client site but I am getting error while signup with the "Disqus account"

Error as below

```
You must re-submit this request with a response to the captcha challenge
```

Please find below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I have checked the source question but there is no answer there https://disqus.com/home/discussion/channel-discussdisqus/re_submit_this_request_with_a_response_to_the_captcha_challenge/

Comment: I am currently seeing this on jetbrains.com.  Perhaps it's an issue on Disqus' end?

Comment: yes it seems like issue is from disqus end as i shared link of disqus forum and it has the same issue inside.

Comment: yes, same promblem, cant make comment on htmlbook

Comment: i even cancel add block in chrome, same problem